# jdbc help translating mapping char to string when updating a database

Tags: java, jdbc, mapping

I am trying to map a particular character to show the full word so in this code below I have a translate method, a select method that is selecting from the remote database and update method that updates those column to my local database.

My remote database has a column called `profile_ind` this columns only has single chars `B,C,F,P,S,W` in the data, and once I do the update I want to be able to translate it to the full word only without the chars.  `B = BENIGN, C = CUSTOMER, F = FRAME, P = PPCOS, S = STANDARD, W = W-RED`

And in my update method I want to call that translate method. `cos_profile_type` is the column on my local database that I want to update to either  `BENIGN, CUSTOMER, FRAME,PPCOS,STANDARD,W-RED`  depending on `profile_ind` column in the remote db. How can I implement it ? how can i call that translate method in the update method when I  set the ? in that statement.

```
public static  String translate(String indicator) throws Exception {

    if (indicator == null || indicator.length() == 0) return "";
    if (indicator.equals("B")) return "BENIGN";
    if (indicator.equals("C")) return "CUSTOMER";
    if (indicator.equals("F")) return "FRAME";
    if (indicator.equals("P")) return "PPCOS";
    if (indicator.equals("S")) return "STANDARD";
    if (indicator.equals("W")) return "W-RED";
    System.out.println(indicator);
    return "";
}

public static void selectRecordsIcore() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();



    String selectTableSQL = "SELECT profile_id, ingress_flag, egress_flag, ce_ingress_flag, ce_egress_flag, profile_ind from COS_PROFILE"
    + " WHERE profile_id >= ? AND profile_id <= ? ;";

    try {
        dbConnection = getInformixConnection();    //connects to ICORE database
        System.out.println("ICORE Select Statement: " +  selectTableSQL);

        //Gets the max profile_id record
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet r = statement.executeQuery("SELECT max(profile_id) AS rowcount FROM COS_PROFILE");       
        r.next();
        int maxCount = r.getInt("rowcount");
        System.out.println("COS_PROFILE table has " + maxCount + " row(s).");

        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectTableSQL);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, maxCount);

        // execute select SQL statement
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

          updateRecordIntoBids();


    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        System.out.println("inside the finally block ICORE  " + new Timestamp(date.getTime()));

         if (rs != null) {
             rs.close();
         }
         if (statement != null) {
             statement.close();
             System.out.println("ICORE Statement Connection is closed");
         }
         if (preparedStatement != null) {
             preparedStatement.close();
             System.out.println("ICORE PreparedStatement Connection is closed");
         }

         if (dbConnection != null) {
             dbConnection.close();
             System.out.println("Database ICORE Connection is closed");
         }

      }
}

private static void updateRecordIntoBids() throws SQLException {

      Connection dbConnection = null;
      PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
      Statement statement = null;
      dbConnection = getOracleConnection(); //connects to BIDS database


        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();

    //Gets the max profile_id record
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
          dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
        ResultSet r = statement.executeQuery("SELECT count (*) AS rowcount FROM traffic_profile_temp");             
        r.next();
        int maxCount = r.getInt("rowcount");
        System.out.println("Traffic_profile_temp table before update has " + maxCount + " row(s).");

        String updateTableSQL = 
                "UPDATE traffic_profile_temp SET pe_ingress_flag  = ?, "
             + " pe_egress_flag = ?,"
             + " ce_ingress_flag = ?,"
             + " ce_egress_flag = ?, "
             + " cos_profile_type = ? "
             + " WHERE traffic_profile_id = ?  ";

        // execute update SQL statement
         System.out.println("BIDS Update Statement: " + updateTableSQL);

        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
        System.out.println("Updating Bids Database in process ...");

         try {
             int rowCount = 0;  
             int expectedId = 1;
             int first = 0;

             while (rs.next()) {


                 String ingressflag = rs.getString("ingress_flag");     //BIDS column is pe_ingress_flag
                 String egressflag = rs.getString("egress_flag");       //BIDS column is pe_egress_flag
                 String ceingressflag = rs.getString("ce_ingress_flag"); //BIDS column is ce_ingress_flag
                 String ceegressflag = rs.getString("ce_egress_flag");  //BIDS column is ce_egress_flag
                 String profileind = rs.getString("profile_ind");       //BIDS column is cos_profile_type
                 int profileid = rs.getInt("profile_id");                //BIDS column is traffic_profile_id

                preparedStatement.setString(1, ingressflag);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, egressflag);
                preparedStatement.setString(3, ceingressflag);
                preparedStatement.setString(4, ceegressflag);
                preparedStatement.setString(5, profileind);
                preparedStatement.setInt(6, profileid);

                preparedStatement.addBatch();
                rowCount++;


                if(expectedId == profileid){
                    if(first == 0){
                        first = expectedId-1;
                    }

               }

                if(expectedId != profileid){
                    if(first > 0){
                        System.out.println ("Profile id "+first+" to "+(expectedId-1)+" update.");
                        first = 0;
                    }
                    System.out.println ("Profile id "+expectedId+" to "+(profileid-1)+" missing.");
                    expectedId = profileid;
               }

               expectedId++;
           }
              if(first > 0){
                    System.out.println("Profile id "+first+" to "+(expectedId-1)+" update.");
                    first = 0;
                    }

          preparedStatement.executeBatch();

         dbConnection.commit();
          System.out.println("Record(s) Updated  : " + rowCount +  new Timestamp(date.getTime()));

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("Update records Failed!! " +  e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        System.out.println("inside the finally block BIDS"  +  " timestamp " +  new Timestamp(date.getTime()));


     if (statement != null) {
         statement.close();
         System.out.println("BIDS Statement Connection is closed");
     }
         if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
             System.out.println("BIDS PreparedStatement Connection is closed");
         }

         if (dbConnection != null) {
             dbConnection.close();
             System.out.println("Database BIDS Connection is closed");
         }

      }


}
```

Comment: I figure it out  after i added the translate call to my code `String profileind = translate(rs.getString("profile_ind"));` it worked.